# Azure Functions - Call a Secured Webserver API from an Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

If I want to call an API that requires authorization from an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenent, how would I authorize the request from an Azure Function that happens based on a trigger?

Since the function makes a call to the API based on a trigger, there is no user-interacton, and happens in the background. So I would assume a bearer token needs to be sent?

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 1):

As you implied, you will first need to get an access token from AAD B2C, then use that token to access your API.  I would suggest you refer to the MS Docs for getting an access token from AAD B2C, it's pretty detailed and should be what you need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#request-a-token

Then add that access token to your auth headers (using HttpClient) and make the call to you API.  There really isn't anything Azure Function specific/dependent to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My concern with requesting a token that way is that it seems that it depends on a User interactively signing into their account. But since no user would be interacting with the Azure Function, no User would be able to sign into the account.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually wrong in this instance.  I assumed B2C supported the client credential flow, but a quick search reveals that it doesn't support it directly.  Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#current-limitations and you will see the workaround that MS suggests.  This would not help if you need delegated user identity (acting as a specific user).  If you need that, then I don't think you can achieve that within an Azure Function (non-interactive flow).

Answer (score 0):

Treat you B2C tenant as if it was a regular AAD, i.e. look at it through the regular AAD blade and configure standard client credentials OAuth2 flow that way. That is possible. Client creds is only not supported for applications registered through the B2C blade. Have a look at a sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code#daemon-applications-accessing-web-apis-with-the-applications-identity) to see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample. It shows how to use the Microsoft identity platform to access the data from a protected Web API, in a non-interactive process:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi